# In Safari on iOS, is it possible to have a button that copies text to the clipboard?

Tags: javascript, ios, safari, copy, clipboard

I am wondering if it is possible in Safari on iOS to have a button that copies text to the clipboard.

Answer (score 0):

Due to the lack of example code I can answer in a general term: Yes

You need to exploit [ClipboardEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ClipboardEvent) HTML API to play with it.

Although, due to security considerations, the user will have to take an action for it to work. It's the same as opening popups.

Comment: MDN paints a misleading picture of browser support. You have to look closely at the fine print on "http://caniuse.com/#feat=clipboard to see what actual support is:

"Partial support in IE refers using a non-standard method of interacting with the clipboard. For other browsers it refers to not supporting the ClipboardEvent constructor."

Basically that means you can't programmatically create the event right now in any browser other than Firefox.